# Wrapper for CGFloat Error

Tags: ios, objective-c, cgfloat

In my CGFloat wrapper Im getting an error `Returning CGFloat (aka Double) from a function result type CGfloat aka double take the address with &`

```
+(CGFloat*)pointData;
```

//

```
+(CGFloat *)pointData{


    NSInteger savedInt = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"savedPointForText"];
    CGFloat textPoint = (CGFloat)savedInt;

    if(textPoint <1) {

        textPoint = 18.0;
    }


    return textPoint;
}
```

If I do `return &textPoint;` I get a warning that address of stack memory with local variable "textpoint" returned

Comment: `+(CGFloat)pointData;` without the "*"?

Comment: Yep that will do it thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, you can just return the `CGFloat` itself, if you change the signature to:

```
+ (CGFloat)pointData {
```

You need `CGFloat *` in case you don't want to return the variable (perhaps because you actually need to manipulate more than one variable):

```
+ (void)changePointData:(CGFloat *)pointData {
    NSInteger savedInt = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"savedPointForText"];
    *pointData = (CGFloat)savedInt;

    if (*pointData < 1) {    
        *pointData = 18.0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry - forgot to change the parameter name. It is a really useful pattern to know.

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
+(CGFloat)pointData{

    //Your code
}
```

Hope it helps.